# In which cases does git automatically update the author (no flags)

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I wonder in which cases does git change the author of commits if no flags/commans to change the author are provided?

#### Context

I created some commits, created a merge request/pull request.
Some other person is responsible for managing all the rebasing and some merge conflicts, etc.

When we later were looking for some commits we saw that the author was changed to that second person. But i don't think they changed it deliberately.

Comment: Did you ask them?

Comment: @chepner yes, and i do believe them, because there would not be any benefit.

Comment: @LinFelix It doesn't. Rebase copies author and author's date but changes commiter and their date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't change commits.  Git literally *can't* change commits.  So you're fundamentally asking the wrong question here.  Fortunately your context provides some clues as to what question you probably meant to ask, which is:

#### When using a Git command that copies commits, when does Git change the author field?

Both `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` work to copy commits, and both use the same strategy here—in fact, `git rebase` literally invokes `git cherry-pick` in some versions of `git rebase`, and in others it shares enough code to think about them as being the same here.

Both commands normally create their new commits with you (whoever "you" are, the person running `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`) as the *committer* but with the original author as the *author*.  Since Git stores these as two separate entities for each commit, that works fine.  Sites like GitHub will generally show both users for the copied commits, though this kind of display is up to the hosting site.

There is one large exception, and that is when using `--reset-author` as a flag, but you did say to exclude flags.

There's another question you could ask here, but it's not a Git question, it's a hosting-site-specific question:

#### When using Bitbucket / GitHub / GitLab and merging a pull/merge request, when does the hosting site generate one or more new commits instead of using the original commit(s), and who is the author and committer of the new commit(s)?

These answers will vary from one hosting site to another.  GitHub, notably, generates new commits if you use either <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> merge modes.  The former effectively uses `git rebase`,<sup>1</sup> so it behaves like a forced rebase followed by a `git merge`.  The latter effectively uses `git merge --squash`, which generates a single new commit with "you" (the person using the clicky web button) as both author and committer.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Effectively" because GitHub use their own code plus libgit2 to do everything, rather than using command-line Git.